# Error running bison on windows "conflicts: 1 shift/reduce, 1 reduce/reduce C:\GnuWin32\bin\bison.exe: m4: Invalid argument"

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

Learning lex yacc for first time.
but no code in bison is running
ERROR: C:\GnuWin32\bin\bison.exe: m4: Invalid argument
I reinstalled bison checked the path but still the error is not going.
Something wrong with m4 file

PS C:\Users\Vishwajeet\Desktop\lab\Compiler\D2> bison -dy gm2.y
conflicts: 1 shift/reduce, 1 reduce/reduce
C:\GnuWin32\bin\bison.exe: m4: Invalid argument

path: C:\GnuWin32\bin path without space

```
%{
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int yylex();
%}

%token A B C NL

%%

stmt: S NL  { printf("valid string\n");
              exit(0); }
;
S: X Y | W
;
X: A X B |
;
Y: C Y |
;
W: A W C | Z
;
Z: B Z |
;
%%

int yyerror(char *msg)
 {strong text
  printf("invalid string\n");
  exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: What's the full command line you use to run bison? (please edit it into to your question. Be precise; copy and paste from your terminal. Or from your build log, if you're using some kind of build tool/IDE.)

Comment: (This problem usually has to do with spaces in filepaths, by the way.)

Comment: Bison is installed on path without space C:\GnuWin32\bin.

Comment: there is also this: https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=31873

Comment: I don't know a solution, but I had the same problem and running the exact command in a make file, e.g. `calc.tab.c calc.tab.h: calc.y
 bison -t -v -d calc.y` produces no error for me

Answer (score -1):

Most likely then, you have another m4 in your path
environment variable before the gnuwin32 one that
accompanies bison. Check this carefully.
You can set the path C:\GnuWin32\bin at the top of the environment path variable list.
[Just move up this path on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGq9k.png)